# Format timespan as TotalMilliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting, timespan

I am writing a simple ASP.Net page, where I have several fields, one of them is for timeout. I want to display it as milliseconds (but still want to have a timespan instead of int/string). I am writing following code:

```
<input asp-for="Entry.Interval" asp-format="{0:fff}" type="text" class="form-control">
```

But here is a problem. This format is not working as expected. I expect `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).ToString("fff")` to return `120000`, but it returns `000`. It's obviosly becuase `TimeSpan` uses `Milliseconds` property, which is zero in this example, but I need `TotalMilliseconds`.

Is there some format which force to show entire `TimeSpan` in desired units? I really don't want to write an integer field and map it manually on this `TimeSpan`.

Comment: The `.ToString("fff")` will return the entire `TimeSpan` formatted as "fff", being the frames/milliseconds to 3 characters. Similarly, if you printed "ss", you'd get the seconds to 2 characters. You say you need `TotalMilliseconds` - which is correct and would give you `120000` as a `double`. I'm not sure where you're struggling? What is your desired output?

Comment: @GeoffJames when you are specifiing a value to be binded, you cannot call propertyies or methods. When I write `asp-for="Entry.Interval"` it takes a value from it, then applies `format` and renders. Then, on submit it doing it at reverse order, parsing the value and returning a final result. I can't use `TotalMilliseconds`, becuase in this case it will renders value correctly, but will be unable to parse it on postback.

Comment: I see, so you're looking to display `Entry.Interval` (being 2 minutes) as `120000` on the page? What type is `Entry.Interval`? `TimeSpan`?

Comment: What is it the value being passed to your postback method as? Could you post your postback method in your question, please?

Comment: @GeoffJames it is passed `as is`, it's a text input so its value is just a number. So mapper parses it as `120000 days`. I think there is no other way than write a wrapper as provided below. Becuase it's not a WebForm, when we post the value back we don't know what it was originally. It's just a string `120000` and there is no way to determine from where it is taken. Another way is attributes, which binder can use in parsing process, but unfortunly I cannot add it to entity model. Thank you for answering, it was useful.

Comment: I see. I agree, I think the only way to do it is using a separate property as the answer below. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define another property only to be used in binding

```
class Entry
{
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    public int IntervalMS
    {
        get { return (int)Interval.TotalMilliseconds; }
        set { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(value); }
    }
    //other stuff...
}
```

And then

```
<input asp-for="Entry.IntervalMs" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Comment: You are missing a cast, `TotalMilliseconds` returns `double` instead of `int`